# How to find the folder/file into which nautilus writes data while wiping free space

Tags: nautilus

I had decided to use Wipe available Disk-space in Nautilus. I did it by using the right click menu in the Home folder.
It started fine and then as i was viewing the other files i had, by mistake i closed its window while it was in progress.

Now its showing zero free-space available in the Home folder(which is where i had decided to use it). So which file or folder do i need to delete in order to bring back all the available free space i had before starting the wipe available disk space in Nautilus?

Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: I don't have such options on Nautilus. Please describe *exactly* what you did. Add screenshots if you must.

Comment: how to add screen shots ? the print screen button does not seem to work

Comment: in the provided duplicate it does not say what to do after you cancel the wipe available diskspace by mistake

Comment: Oh, but it contains this link in one answer: https://tails.boum.org/doc/encryption_and_privacy/secure_deletion/index.en.html#index4h1 (Emptying the trash is relevant). Please tell us if it works.

Comment: There is no file at all besides the ones which were available from start(before i started the wipe available diskspace). No file in trash folder either.

Comment: Have you enabled hidden files/folders (CTRL+H)? If so and you can't file folders similar to the one mentioned above, I have no further suggestions at the moment.

Comment: What folder does `baobab` / Disk Usage Analyzer say is really big?

Comment: it showed the home folder and located the tmp file. it was buried deep inside one of the folders, no idea thou why it had to be there as i had not visited that folder earlier at all.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Disk Usage Analyzer and make sure to run it as root. Otherwise it will show errors and will leave you pondering as to why its not working. The culprit folder tmp was actually showing only 4.47KB when i checked its size so i had been mislead the first time i checked. I simply deleted that folder and got back the free space which i had lost earlier thanks to Disk Usage Analyzer which i had run as root.